# I there a better way then many if statements

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a better and shorter way to do this. Like with a list?

```py
url = input("Url: ")
if '.com' in url:
    print("has .com")
elif '.uk' in url:
    print('has uk')
elif '.au' in url:
    print('hass au')
elif:
    print('has nothing i the list')
```

I am using python3.

Comment: Given that your code is already working, and you just want suggestions on how to maybe improve upon it, your question might work better on our sister side, [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Better how? What are you looking for? What are you trying to improve? What is your criterion, and what do the placeholders represent? There is so much mossing information here...

Comment: The code in the question won't even work (the last `elif` should be an `else`). Also the logic does not look right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're doing the same thing with different parameters, a `for` loop sounds like a competitive candidate:

```
for s in [".com", ".uk", ".au"]:
    if s in url:
        print("has %s" % s)
        break
else:
    print("has nothing")
```

The `else` block will be executed if the `for` loop completes normally (instead of a `break` or an exception), so the above construct is a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. Another possible approach:

```py
accepted_domains = ['.com', '.uk', '.au']

url = input("Url: ")
try: 
   print("has " + accepted_domains[accepted_domains.index(url)])
except ValueError:
   print('has nothing i the list')
```